# manage.py datadump of a large database in Django 1.1 (creating testdatabase)

Tags: mysql, django, django-fixtures, manage.py

To be able to do some decent unittests I want to create a testdatabase. After reading the Django docs, I came to the conclusion that the best way to do this is by creating a testdatabase from the actual database, with the use of fixtures.

To create such a fixture, one is to run:

```
./manage.py dumpdata appname --indent 2
```

After dumping, I want to edit the file, and select the data I actually want to use. However, dumping it almost crashes my PC (the scripts starts trashing I think). Also, it seems to first get all data in memory, and then print it all out at once.

The database I'm using is MySQL

**Is there a way to get the data out the database without crashing my PC, in a format usable as fixture?**

(an alternative which I'm considering is redefining the default datamanager for the objects with lots of rows, to return only needed rows, but that seems like a rather nasty hack, which I'd rather not apply)

Comment: You know it's possible to select specific tables inside the app using this syntax? `./manage.py dumpdata appname.modelname --indent 2`

Comment: but the problem is one of the tables is really large (it's a zipcode table of all of the Netherlands)

Comment: There's no way you're gonna be able to dump more then 13 million records using plain dumpdata. Your best best would indeed be using a custom model manager. Note that this isn't a nasty hack and even the preferred way of handling this in django.

Comment: A *custom* handler is in no way a hack, I agree, but to be able to use dumpdata, you need to edit the *default* manager :(

Comment: Hmm, you're right. Well, in that case your better of creating your own dumpdata command (check django/core/manage/commands/dumpdata.py). I must agree that editing (or overwriting) the default manager is a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at this [ticket](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/5423) and apply the supplied patch. @ramiro recently ran tests to compare the trunk against his latest patch and you can see there is a *huge* difference in memory consumption at the expense of processing time:

[image: Unpatched runk]
[image]